# Xamarin: The underlying android.support.v7.widget.CardView class not added to the .apk

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I'm trying to use the CardView in my Xamarin Android project.

I added CardView through Nuget. Works fine. Displayed in the editor (IntelliSense) fine. Compiled, apk built and deplyed into device fine.

I have set the androidtargetversion too as recommended.

But it gives me runtime error
`Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.CardView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/WinterNightc.Droid-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/WinterNightc.Droid-1, /system/lib]]`
whenever I try to create an instance of CardView.

After studying the error for about a week now I have identified what happens is that though the C# binding class for CardView ( Android.Support.V7.Widget.CardView) works fine (therefore no compile error in C# code) the underlying  android.support.v7.widget.CardView (notice simple letters) is not added to apk/not accessible in the runtime of the application.

I checked the project\obj\debug folder, it does not contain any .jar file other than mono.android.jar. I think it should contain the jar library for cardview (i don't know how mono works).

Finally I tried to import the .jar libraries manually into VisualStudio and set built action to AndroidJavaLibrary. (i don't need to do this under normal circumstances right?). It gave a slightly different runtime error.
`Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.cardview.R$styleable`

I installed xamarin on my Azure VM and tried to do this. Same error again(why am only I getting this error no matter what computer i use)

I have done cleaning, reinstalling sdks and almost evrything possible in the past week.

I'm stuck on this error for almost a week now.
Help me

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this issue?

Comment: @Nick yes
extract
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip
to
C:\Users\Sadeep\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.4.0.0\content\

adjust username and version

Comment: if you have done right 'm2repository' directory should be inside 'content'.
Don't forget to 'Clean solution'

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got mine working by rolling everything back to 23.2.1. I will be sure to try your solution as well.